# Powershell: Remotely Unzip from file-share using invoke-command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to unzip a file remotely. The file-share the ZIP is on uses a different credential
This is the command I ran.

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $compname -ScriptBlock 
{
         Expand-Archive -Path "\\share\somefolder\myfile.zip" -DestinationPath "\\share\somefolder" 
}
```

I get an error stating username/password incorrect for accessing the share.

The problem is, the account I use to access $compname is not the same account I use to access the share the zip is on. I don't have a common account that can access both.

Incidentally, running the expand-archive by taking RDP to $compname works because it uses the saved credentials from the credential manager. Invoke-command on the other hand seems to be trying to access the share with the credentials used to connect to the remote computer.

Things I have tried

1. Mapping a network drive beforehand, but that doesn't get
   recognised as a valid path when accessed via invoke-command.
2. Mapping a network drive on the fly inside the invoke-command
   option, and then using that mapped drive with expand-archive. This
   showed the most promise as I could get it working via
   enter-pssession, but of course this won't work in a script am trying to automate and when
   I created a new session via new-pssession and passing that to
   invoke-command, it again failed to work.

Does anyone have suggestions on a possible approach? I might revisit option #2 to see if I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried the `-Credential` parameter on `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: The powershell script is already running off the userid that has remote access to $compname so i didn't pass the credential explicitly. If you meant about passing the credential that has access to the share itself, wouldn't that fail as the account i use to write to the share doesn't have remote access to $compname?